# Change Permissions using command line windows?

Tags: command-line, window

I am looking to give Write Permissions on the folder from a commandline Utility.
I am using ICACL to change the permissions.

I have network shared folder with write permissions and I have to change subfolder and its' files read permission to write.

I am trying to understand how to use the command.

Comment: `I am trying to understand how to use the command.` OK: and what is your question?

Comment: I am looking how to use the command and its parameters